# compiling llvm on linux x86_64: suggestions on optimization flags?

Tags: optimization, gcc, compiler-construction, installation, llvm

I am compiling llvm v3.0 on a linux x86_64 on an intel double core and I would like to have some feedback on the optimization flags that need to be specified. I am compiling with gcc and I would start with '-O3', but I would like to know if there are any other flags that you recommend - maybe also architecture dependent.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case you are going to use llvm on the same machine as you are compiling it, I suggest

```
-O3 -march=native -mtune=native
```

To enable all supported features of your cpu e.g. sse,avx,…